# Storybook fails with "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'base16')" for some components

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, storybook, angular-storybook

I am trying to show my Angular components in Storybook. For some components this works, but for others, I keep getting shown this exception:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'base16')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'base16')
    at ./node_modules/rfc4648/lib/index.mjs (http://localhost:4400/vendors-node_modules_angular-auth-oidc-client_fesm2020_angular-auth-oidc-client_mjs.iframe.bundle.js:14476:66)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:4400/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:4400/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:322:25)
    at ./node_modules/angular-auth-oidc-client/fesm2020/angular-auth-oidc-client.mjs (http://localhost:4400/vendors-node_modules_angular-auth-oidc-client_fesm2020_angular-auth-oidc-client_mjs.iframe.bundle.js:7520:65)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:4400/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:4400/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:322:25)
...
```

The file where the exception occurs, `index.mjs`, looks like this:

```js
// Generated by rollup-plugin-mjs-entry

import cjs from './index.js';

export const base16 = cjs.base16;
export const base32 = cjs.base32;
export const base32hex = cjs.base32hex;
export const base64 = cjs.base64;
export const base64url = cjs.base64url;
export const codec = cjs.codec;
export default cjs;
```

Apparently, it is generated by something called [rollup-plugin-mjs-entry](https://github.com/swansontec/rollup-plugin-mjs-entry).

When I step through that code, I observe the following events:

- `index.js` gets executed, it exports an object with all the properties expected on `cjs` in `index.mjs`
- execution passes by a file called `bootstrap`, which again exports an object with all properties
- execution arrives at a file called `hot module replacement`, which calls something called `require2` for the request to `index.js`
- when I step into that call, execution enters `index.mjs`, and `cjs` appears to be `undefined`

I am not sure how or even where to fix this:

- Is there anything wrong with my Storybook config?
- Is there anything wrong with my particular `.stories.ts` file?
- Is this a bug in Storybook?
- Is this an issue with Webpack?
- Is there anything wrong with my TypeScript setup?
- Is there anything wrong with any of the 3rd party packages we pull in?
- ...?

**How can I start to debug this error?**

(I know you cannot *guess* what exactly is the error in my particular project. First and foremost, this question is about what part or aspect of the application I need to look at to start with. I would post more code if I just knew what part of the code or settings might be relevant at all.)

---

Here is a shortened version of one of the affected `.stories.ts` files:

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Meta, moduleMetadata } from '@storybook/angular';

// imports of 6 additional custom components and a custom pipe (all of which are used in MyComponent), as well as a mock data object
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';

export default {
    title: 'MyComponent',
    component: MyComponent,
    decorators: [
        moduleMetadata({
            imports: [HttpClientModule],
            declarations:[/* declarations of the six imported components */],
            providers:[/* declaration of the imported pipe */]
        }),
    ],
} as Meta<MyComponent>;

export const Primary = {
    render: (args: MyComponent) => ({
        props: args,
    }),
    args: {
        myData: /* the mock data object */
    },
};
```

Comment: Could you share one of the failing component module and also the related storybook file?

Comment: @Wandrille: I have added one of the failing `.stories.ts` files. I'm not sure how I can add the "failing component module"; `MyComponent` on its own already has almost 2000 LoC.

Comment: Same issue here since Storybook 7, with Angular 15.
It seems the error comes from a dependency called "rfc4648" used by the library "angular-auth-oidc-client" internally.

Also, I have many warnings in console, also caused by "rfc4648".

Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @AdrienSAULNIER: Not yet, I'm still looking for one, and hoping someone might answer here. The pointer that it is due to one specific dependency gives me some hope this may be temporary or at least not a systematic error with my setup, though. Are the errors you are seeing completely the same, including the message referring to the `base16` field?

Comment: Yes, exaclty the same. I have an `AuthService` which inject services from `angular-auth-oidc-client`. If the component itself or one of its children inject the `AuthService`, the error appears.

Also, after Storybook started, I have warnings in console related to `base16` : `./node_modules/rfc4648/lib/index.mjs 4:22-32export 'default' (imported as 'cjs') was not found in './index.js' (possible exports: __esModule, base16, base32, base32hex, base64, base64url, codec)`

Comment: @AdrienSAULNIER: Fascinating - that means this particular error message is not specific to my project. Phew! If this has not been mentioned on Storybook's issue tracker yet, I'm going to open a ticket in the course of today.

Comment: In fact, IDK if an issue should be opened on Storybook... or angular-auth-oidc-client ! :x

Comment: @AdrienSAULNIER: Looks like someone has already [logged an issue with Storybook](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/22542).